Is the stateless-ask program deployed on mainnet somewhere?
Has someone or some organization deployed the stateless ask program on mainnet somewhere?
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/stateless-asks

I found one but it is outdated.
https://github.com/jarry-xiao/stateless-offer-client/blob/32a5c80b3de6acab7edac300b39e6d9201cb2db8/src/utils/ids.ts#L60
https://solscan.io/account/SAtnofysr9Uxk7m9YphxwfL5E3wyZJWUzjwA29Gw3tQ
If you found a different one let me know.
Also interested to see other projects that interact with this program.

I don't think the program was ever modified substantially, so that version might actually be good! What makes you think it's outdated?

@JonC I thought so because the last transactions displayed on solscan were 2 years ago. I have since decided I need to deploy a modified version of this. But I am still interested in talking to people that use this!

Ah gotcha, it might not be actively used. But deploying your own version is a great solution too!
